# Scrapy- Getting several items from one link

Tags: python, css, scrapy

So my goal is to scrape a list from a CSV file (I have that part figured out) but when I try running my program on a test URL, that URL is scraped several times and returning the results I want once. I'll clarify with my code and some screen shots.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import LowesspiderItem
from scrapy.http import Request
import requests



class LowesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'lowes'
def start_requests(self):
    start_urls = ['https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42',
    'https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=RA36']
    for url in start_urls:
        yield Request(url,
                    headers={'Cookie': 'sn=2333;'}, #Preset a location
                    meta={'dont_merge_cookies': True, #Allows location cookie to get through
                    'url':url}) #Using to get the product SKU

def parse(self, response):
    items = response.css('.grid-container')
    for product in items:
        item = LowesspiderItem()

    #get product price
        productPrice = product.css('.art-pd-price::text').get()
    #get SKU
        productSKU = response.meta['url']
        productSKU = productSKU.split('=')[-1]



        item["productSKU"] = productSKU
        item["productPrice"] = productPrice


        yield item
```

---

```
2020-04-21 14:09:48 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2020-04-21 14:09:48 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2020-04-21 14:09:48 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2020-04-21 14:09:48 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lowes.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2020-04-21 14:09:48 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644> from <GET https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=8654RM-42>
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095> from <GET https://www.lowes.com/search?searchTerm=RA36>
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644> (referer: None)
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': '1,449.95', 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}

2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Ducted-Red-Matte-Wall-Mounted-Range-Hood-Common-42-Inch-Actual-42-in/1001440644>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095> (referer: None)
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': 'RA36'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': 'RA36'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': 'RA36'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': '2,549.99', 'productSKU': 'RA36'}

2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': 'RA36'}
2020-04-21 14:09:49 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.lowes.com/pd/ZLINE-KITCHEN-BATH-Professional-Deep-Recessed-6-Burners-Convection-Stainless-Steel-Common-36-in-Actual-36-in/1000525095>
{'productPrice': None, 'productSKU': 'RA36'}
```

So the results I would want would just be something like this:
{'productPrice': '1,449.95', 'productSKU': '8654RM-42'}

However with my program I get a hand full of repeated results which I assume is being caused by my top level item where it is iterating over the for loop

```
items = response.css('.grid-container')
    for product in items:
        item = LowesspiderItem()
```

Also here's a screenshot of the Excel Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two URLs you are scraping are single product pages, so you shouldn't need the `for product in items` loop.

Comment: @chrisHG no worries :-)